# Emacs screen drawing issues over SSH

Tags: virtualbox, ssh, emacs

I have a Ubuntu 13.10 server installed in VirtualBox on a Windows host. When I connect to it via SSH (tried Putty, Cygwin's OpenSSH and OS X terminal from a different machine) Emacs appears to be having screen (re)drawing issues. Here's my test scenario:

1. emacs ~/.bashrc
2. C-s HIST (incremental search for "HIST")
3. keep hitting C-s (aka jump to the next search result)

After repeating no. 3 a few times, I end up with this:

[image]

The problem doesn't occur when using VirtualBox console. 12.04 works fine as well. Tried the emacs23-nox package, the latest emacs from `ppa:cassou/emacs`, `emacs -q` (skip start-up files), running it in a "screen" session, changing `LC_ALL to C` - all to no avail.

Any ideas what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Try setting the `TERM=xterm` environment variable before starting emacs (`export TERM=xterm` or `TERM=xterm emacs`) or look in your Putty settings for the terminal type.

Comment: I'm afraid neither xterm nor xterm-256color help.

Answer (score 3):

Huh, strange story. Changing the number of CPUs in VirtualBox from 2 to 1 fixed the problem.

Comment: Had the same issue, fixed after changing the number of CPUs. Really strange behaviour.

Comment: I confirm such behavior on vagarant with ubuntu/trusty64 box.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (brute force) workaround. This does NOT require you to set the number of CPUs to 1.

Add the following to your init.el (your emacs settings):

```
(add-hook 'isearch-update-post-hook 'redraw-display)
```